# AndoidX Lifecycle LiveData with Type arguments

Tags: xamarin, android-livedata, dao, androidx, lifecycle

I am having a problem with defining LiveData in DAO AndroidX Xamarin

I have added the AndroidX lifecycle LiveData nugets.
I get CS0308 The non generic type LiveData cannot be used with Type arguments

`[Query(Value = "SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY priority DESC")] LiveData<List<Note>> GetAllNotes();`

Any advice on how to fix this?
[image]

I searched everywhere for a solution. Tried the CrossPlatform plugin described here:
[CrossplatformLiveData](https://medium.com/@jakdor00/crossplatformlivedata-xamarin-lightweight-mvvm-library-280ab2857bec)

Comment: shouldn't it be `List<LiveData>`?

Comment: sadly no.  see here example in Java:
https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47

in Xamarin this syntax seems not to work